# c# vb.net convert

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is there a Visual Studio AddOn to convert c# to vb.net ? I tried using the websites that do it real quick, but for longer more complicated code it comes up with lots of errors.  Or any good third party app that does it?

ERROR:  'Context' is not a member of 'Default2'

Then it points to this top line in XHTML

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>
```

Comment: No, but you can use this: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: That's the one that does a good job, but I have over 10 errors that I can't fix because I can't read vb.net very well

Comment: @ScottSelby - post a question about the specific bits you are having problems with.

Comment: telerik too has a converter.http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: There's no real help to convert asp.net pages like you are using, language converters are based on pure code.  Not the weirdo mix of markup and code that asp.net consumes.  More to the point, there isn't really any reason to make this kind of conversion, vb.net works just as well as C#, there's no functional improvement.  If you violently dislike vb.net in the code-behind then there's a cure for that, rewrite it.  That will just take you a while to catch up, possibly just adding bugs but no real functional improvement.  Only you, or you boss, can make that call.

Comment: @ScottSelby I too have had problems with the http://codeconverter.com sites in rare cases and thats when I resort to Reflector and use Denis Bauer's File Dissasbmler plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code behind page needs to read like this:

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

If you are missing Class Default2 then the following error will generate:

Error   1   'Context' is not a member of 'Default2'.

Comment: No, it's something else, I have that

Answer (score 1):

I have used [SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/articles/FeatureTourCodeConversion.aspx) with good results for code translation